# unable to create a user in chef ( ruby error )

Tags: chef-infra

I am learning chef and I am facing an issue in creating a user for chef

command to execute:

```
chef-server-ctl user-create USER_NAME FIRST_NAME [MIDDLE_NAME] LAST_NAME EMAIL 'PASSWORD' --filepath /path/to/username.pem
```

Error:

```
/opt/opscode/embedded/service/omnibus-ctl/wrap-knife-opc.rb:43:in `block (2 levels) in load_file': undefined method `exitstatus' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from /opt/opscode/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/omnibus-ctl-0.5.0/lib/omnibus-ctl.rb:199:in `call'
        from /opt/opscode/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/omnibus-ctl-0.5.0/lib/omnibus-ctl.rb:199:in `block in add_command_under_category'
        from /opt/opscode/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/omnibus-ctl-0.5.0/lib/omnibus-ctl.rb:736:in `run'
        from /opt/opscode/embedded/service/omnibus-ctl/chef-server-ctl:237:in `<main>'
```

Thank you for your help.

Update 1 :

I was unable to start the chef server too ..

Please find the details :

```
[root@ip-172-31-56-142 chefdk]# chef-server-ctl start
/opt/opscode/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/omnibus-ctl-0.5.0/lib/omnibus-ctl.rb:361:in `run_sv_command_for_service': undefined method `exitstatus' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from /opt/opscode/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/omnibus-ctl-0.5.0/lib/omnibus-ctl.rb:351:in `block in run_sv_command'
        from /opt/opscode/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/omnibus-ctl-0.5.0/lib/omnibus-ctl.rb:350:in `each'
        from /opt/opscode/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/omnibus-ctl-0.5.0/lib/omnibus-ctl.rb:350:in `run_sv_command'
        from /opt/opscode/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/omnibus-ctl-0.5.0/lib/omnibus-ctl.rb:162:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Ctl>'
        from /opt/opscode/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/omnibus-ctl-0.5.0/lib/omnibus-ctl.rb:736:in `run'
        from /opt/opscode/embedded/service/omnibus-ctl/chef-server-ctl:237:in `<main>'
```

Comment: What version of Chef Server? You can check by running `chef-server-ctl --version` I think.

Comment: I think it is not starting also .. Please check as i have updated above

Comment: this is the rpm : chef-server-core-12.7.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm and im doing it on rhel 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by degrading chef version.
and also by updating ruby gems "gems update"

Hope it helps someone looking for this error

Comment: Which version you degraded to?